# I'm having trouble calculating the thermal resistance of a PCB

Tags: mosfet, thermal

I was reading about heat dissipation in PCB boards and I have two big doubts, I want to dissipate the heat generated by a MOSFET that is part of a circuit reverse polarity protector, and I wanted to dissipate the heat using the copper of the PCB, I could calculate the theoretical thermal resistance of the thermal vias, of the upper and lower face of the PCB but what thermal resistance should I use in my calculations and how should I calculate it? Should I assume that the thermal resistance of the upper face, the lower face and the thermal vias are in parallel or in series, how should I calculate the thermal resistance that I have to use in the calculations?

Comment: I'd start here: [Accurate Thermal Calculations on the Back of a Napkin](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slpa015/slpa015.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following articles. The calculation methodology is much too detailed to explain here.

- [How to calculate the thermal resistance of a PCB](https://www.heatsinkcalculator.com/blog/how-to-calculate-the-thermal-resistance-of-a-pcb/)
- [A Quick PCB Thermal Calculation for Power Electronic Devices with Exposed Pad Packages](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9596-D.PDF)

Comment: I used to use the 100°C/W law from TI's recommendations, simply multiply the power to be dissipated by 100°C/W when the PCB is 2oz or 150°C/W when the PCB is 1oz and then I divided it by the dissipation area of ​​copper (in squared), I just think it's close enough for me but your answer is much better

Comment: There is a free calculator that I believe uses the same methodology as the first article. That might save you some time doing the calculations. [PCB Temperature Calculator](https://heatsinkcalculator.com/pcb/free-calculator.html)